# Silverlight bind object in list view using converter

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

Hello I have a little problem with forcing update of list view.
I have ObservableCollection that holds TestClass objects with property Buffer.

ObservalbeCollection reside in ViewModel BaseViewModel

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
   // Constructor
    public MainPage() {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = new BaseViewModel();
    }
  }
}

public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public ObservableCollection<TestClass> TestList { get; set; }
  public BaseViewModel() {
    TestList = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
    TestList.Add(new TestClass() { Buffer = "1", SomeValue = 1 });
    TestList.Add(new TestClass() { Buffer = "2", SomeValue = 2 });
    TestList.Add(new TestClass() { Buffer = "3", SomeValue = 3 });
    TestList.Add(new TestClass() { Buffer = "4", SomeValue = 4 });
  }

  private TestClass selectedItem;
  public TestClass SelectedItem {
    get {
      return selectedItem;
    }
    set {
      if (selectedItem == value) {
        return;
      }

      selectedItem = value;
      selectedItem.Buffer += "a";
      selectedItem.SomeValue += 1;
      selectedItem = null;
      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
  }

  #region notifie property changed
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) {
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
  #endregion
}

public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged  {

  public TestClass() {
  }

  public int SomeValue { get; set; }

  private string buffer;
  public string Buffer {
    get {
      return this.buffer;
    }
    set {
      this.buffer = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("Buffer");        
    }
  }

  #region notifie property changed
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) {
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
  #endregion
}
```

I am binding view model to Page.

Page xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
     xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:PhoneApp2.Test">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <converters:TestClassConverter x:Key="testConverter"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="tasksListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="SomeText"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Buffer}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource testConverter}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now second textblock is properly updated while buffer changes but third is updated only once (at list load). Converter is called only once.

I would like to use 3rd option because:

a) I use TestCalass as a base class for other subclasses

b) I would like to format output depending on TestClass type and use other parameters that are set in TestClass

c) I would like to use Localizable String resources and I wouldn't like to use them in TestClass with is rather POCO object.

Edit:
I have updated source code. The second text box changes while third doesn't. All class expect MainPage reside:

```
namespace PhoneApp2.Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change `TestList` to call `RaisePropertyChanged` when it is updated?

(If you'd provided a full repro I'd have checked myself.)

Comment: How can I change 'TestList' so it call's 'RaisPropertyChanged'. Should I create my own implementation of ObservableList?. I do not change object count in list. I change only some properties of objects in that list. But after this I am setting 'SelectedIndex=null';

Answer (score 0):

A Binding is updated as soon as one of its components is updated AND if this update is announced by an event (like PropertyChanged).

The Binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource testConverter}}"/>
```

is always constant: It's always bound to the very same list entry. So no matter what you change in this very list entry, the Binding isn't informed.

AFAIK the Binding would be re-evaluated if INotifyCollectionChanged's CollectionChanged event is raised. You can do this by raising the CollectionChanged event additionally to the PropertyChanged event you already raise - however this re-evaluates the entire list and can lead to performance issues.

EDIT: You need to raise TestList's CollectionChanged event, which probably isn't possible. You might need to ingerit BaseViewModel from ObservableCollection to do so.

Comment: Maybe I should do it totaly in different way. Any suggestions? Any pattern for this kind of situation?

Comment: Depends on your ultimate goal ... 
- Idea 0 (generally useless): If the converter does NOT need the value, then bind it to Buffer. This will trigger the re-evaluation.
- Idea 1 (dirty hack, fast): add a property to TestClass which returns the class instance itself, bind it to the converter and raise PropertyChanged for Buffer AND for this new property. 
- Idea 2 (clean, versatile, slow): Create Templates for TestClass and all its derived classes, implement a ItemTemplateSelector / DataTemplateSelector like [link](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/12598.aspx)